# Confusion over finding the potential of a conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let

[image]
.

[image]

I don't see how $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$. I don't even know what g(y,z) is supposed to be. We haven't defined the function g(y,z). Is g(y,z) supposed to be the integral of $N$ with respect to $ y$  plus the integral of $ P$  with respect to $ z$ ?

How do we prove that g(y,z) is a function of z alone?

Why did we integrate M with respect to x rather than integrate N with respect to y or P with respect to z?

---

[image]

We did integration on the variable $ x$  to derive $ f(x,y)= "e^xcos(y)+xyz"$. Why aren't we using integration on the variable $ y$  of the function $N$ or $P$  to derive the potential function?

I'm in disbelief that $ h(z)=z^2/2+C$ I think that  $ h(z)$  should be equal to the integral of $ P$  with respect to $ z$  or $ xyz+z^2$.

Answer (score 0):

First we check that $\nabla\times{\bf F} = {\bf 0}$. 
Now we know that a potential, $f(x,y,z)$ such that ${\bf F} = \nabla f$, exists. 
Thus, 
$$(e^x\cos y+yz,xz-e^x\sin y,xy+z) = (f_x,f_y,f_z)$$
for some $f(x,y,z)$. 
It must be the case that 
$f_x = e^x\cos y +yz$ and so by integrating with respect to $x$ we find
$$f(x,y,z) = e^x\cos y + xyz + g(y,z).$$
The function $g(y,z)$ is an integration constant. 
(Note that $g_x = 0$, that is, $g(y,z)$ is a constant with respect to $x$.) 
We must also have 
$$f_y = xz-e^x\sin y.$$
But $f_y = -e^x\sin y + xz + g_y$. 
Thus, $g_y = 0$ and so $g(y,z) = h(z)$. 
Lastly, 
$$f_z = xy+z.$$
But $f_z = xy + h_z$ and so $h_z = z$. 
Thus, $h(z) = z^2/2 + C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: by the mixed partial derivative theorem we must have since $ g_x=0$, then $ g_y$ =0? g is already a function resulting from a derivative?

Comment: @Got: For a function $\phi(x,y,z)$, if $\phi_x = \psi(x,y,z)$ then $\phi = \int \psi(x,y,z)dx + C(y,z)$. The function $\phi$ is known up to a constant of integration. Since we integrated with respect to $x$, this constant is generally a function of $y$ and $z$.

Comment: @Got: For your problem, we find $g_y=0$ by examining $f_y$. ($f_y$ must be the second component of ${\bf F}$.) For your particular ${\bf F}$ we find $g_y=0$, but for another ${\bf F}$ this might not be the case.